# Getting color data in Unity

Tags: google-project-tango

The [release notes](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/release-notes) mention that it is not yet possible to access color data in Unity, but I believe you can attach a callback to a video overlay listener and receive a YUV12 byte array in Unity and manually convert it into RGB565 to display on screen, perhaps with a shader.

Has anyone had success accessing and displaying color data (say in an AR overlay) in Unity? If so, could you share some pointers/code on how to get started?

Answer (score 3):

The video overlay callback works in Unity. Theoretically, you could have the YUV to RGBA shaders and render it in Unity. The only downside of doing that is it will required multiple "memcpy" due to the way Unity texture/color formatting.

The YV12 data packing of Tango is explained in the C-API header: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/struct_tango_image_buffer

It says: "Y samples of width x height are first, followed by V samples, with half the stride and half the lines of the Y data, followed by a U samples with the same dimensions as the V sample."

So I think you could have three Unity Texture each include one of the Y,U,V channel, and pass them into a single shader to compute the RGBA color..

More information about YUV image and the conversion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

Comment: You say the video overlay callback works, but [release notes for the Tango](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/release-notes#november_3_2014_archimedes) state that YUV data isn't available for Unity yet.

Do you have code that works for this? Is this using the provided Unity wrapper or did you write your own?

Comment: I implemented test for the video overlay, sorry I couldn't find the code, but the callbacks were working just fine. The frame rate is low though.. If you take look of the TangoSDK, there is a VideoOverlayListener class implemented, you could inherit from this class to get the YUV data, using _OnImageAvailable callback..

Answer (score 3):

I use the following script to display video overlay on Unity quad mesh. Works on tango tablet. But fps is low, I guess because of the resolution of color camera (1280 x 720).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Tango;

public class CameraBackgorund : VideoOverlayListener
{
    Texture2D backgroundTexture = null;

    // texture data
    bool    isDirty = false;
    byte[]  yuv12   = null;
    int     width;
    int     height;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (isDirty)
        {
            if (backgroundTexture == null)
                backgroundTexture = new Texture2D (width, height);

            // convert from YV12 to RGB
            int size = (int)(width * height);
            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
                {      
                    byte y = yuv12[i * width + j];
                    byte v = yuv12[(i / 2) * (width / 2) + (j / 2) + size];
                    byte u = yuv12[(i / 2) * (width / 2) + (j / 2) + size + (size / 4)];
                    backgroundTexture.SetPixel(j, height - i - 1, YUV2Color(y, u, v));
                }
            }

            // update texture
            backgroundTexture.Apply(true);
            GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.mainTexture = backgroundTexture;

            isDirty = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void _OnImageAvailable(IntPtr callbackContext,
                                              Tango.TangoEnums.TangoCameraId cameraId, 
                                              Tango.TangoImageBuffer imageBuffer)
    {
        if (cameraId != Tango.TangoEnums.TangoCameraId.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR)
            return;

        // allocate for the first time
        width = (int)imageBuffer.width;
        height = (int)imageBuffer.height;
        if (yuv12 == null)
            yuv12 = new byte[width * height * 2];

        // copy data in yv12 format
        IntPtr dataPtr = imageBuffer.data;
        int    offset  = 0;
        Int64  stride  = (Int64)imageBuffer.stride;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i, dataPtr = new IntPtr(dataPtr.ToInt64() + stride), offset += width)
            Marshal.Copy(dataPtr, yuv12, offset, width);
        for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; ++i, dataPtr = new IntPtr(dataPtr.ToInt64() + stride / 2), offset += width / 2)
            Marshal.Copy(dataPtr, yuv12, offset, width / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; ++i, dataPtr = new IntPtr(dataPtr.ToInt64() + stride / 2), offset += width / 2)
            Marshal.Copy(dataPtr, yuv12, offset, width / 2);
        isDirty = true;
    }

    public static Color YUV2Color(byte y, byte u, byte v)
    {
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV
        const float Umax = 0.436f;
        const float Vmax = 0.615f;

        float y_scaled = y / 255.0f;
        float u_scaled = 2 * (u / 255.0f - 0.5f) * Umax;
        float v_scaled = 2 * (v / 255.0f - 0.5f) * Vmax; 

        return new Color(y_scaled + 1.13983f * v_scaled,
                         y_scaled - 0.39465f * u_scaled - 0.58060f * v_scaled,
                         y_scaled + 2.03211f * u_scaled);
    }
}
```

Using Unity WebCamTexture successfully retrieves color, but breaks the depth provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebCamTexture.GetPixel to get the color at the location of the points and make the texture with that information. 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for converting a YV12 to a 2D texture

```
private void YV12_To_Texture2D(byte[] data, uint width, uint height, out Texture2D tex)
{
    tex = new Texture2D((int)width, (int)height);

    uint size = width * height;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int x_index = j;
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                x_index = j - 1;
            }

            // Get the YUV color for this pixel.
            int yValue = data[(i * width) + j];
            int uValue = data[size + ((i / 2) * width) + x_index + 1];
            int vValue = data[size + ((i / 2) * width) + x_index];

            // Convert the YUV value to RGB.
            float r = yValue + (1.370705f * (vValue - 128));
            float g = yValue - (0.689001f * (vValue - 128)) - (0.337633f * (uValue - 128));
            float b = yValue + (1.732446f * (uValue - 128));

            Color co = new Color();
            co.b = b < 0 ? 0 : (b > 255 ? 1 : b / 255.0f);
            co.g = g < 0 ? 0 : (g > 255 ? 1 : g / 255.0f);
            co.r = r < 0 ? 0 : (r > 255 ? 1 : r / 255.0f);
            co.a = 1.0f;

            tex.SetPixel((int)width - j - 1, (int)height - i - 1, co);
        }
    }
}
```